# Choose between 2 available edges during traversal

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm relatively new to Gremlin, and the company I'm with is looking to implement a graph database with some temporary edges within it. Each vertex could have 1 or more edge, and each edge would have a property on it that is essentially isTemporary true/false.

When traversing the graph, if "isTemporary" = true we should follow that edge, otherwise we should follow the edge where "isTemporary" = false.

I.e.,

`A-[isTemporary:true, value 1] -> B`

`A-[isTemporary:false, value 2] -> C`

`B-[isTemporary: false, value 3] -> D`

Running a single gremlin query should return A->B->D in this case.

I've looked through TinkerPop3 documentation, and it seems like "choose" may be what I want to use here, but all the examples seem to return a value, when what I want is a traversal to come back so I can repeatedly act on the traversal.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be looking for the [`coalesce`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.3/reference/#coalesce-step) step.

Considering this graph:

```
g.addV().as('a').property('name', 'A').
  addV().as('b').property('name', 'B').
  addV().as('c').property('name', 'C').
  addV().as('d').property('name', 'D').
  addE('someLink').from('a').to('b').
    property('isTemporary', true).property('value', 1).
  addE('someLink').from('a').to('c').
    property('isTemporary', false).property('value', 2).
  addE('someLink').from('b').to('d').
    property('isTemporary', false).property('value', 3)
```

The following query will return all paths from A to D, attempting to traverse via `isTemporary: true` edges if present, or via `isTemporary: false` edges otherwise (coalesce step), iteratively.

```
g.V().has('name', 'A').
  repeat(
    coalesce(
      outE().has('isTemporary', true).inV(),
      outE().has('isTemporary', false).inV()
    )
  ).
  until(has('name', 'D')).
  path().by('name')
```

Result:

```
==>[A,B,D]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is likely exactly what I'm looking for, I'll test it here shortly. I love when it's just a question of thinking about the problem wrong. We're migrating from Cypher, and the liberal use of unwind to solve problems like this has made the migration tricky.